# Add an invoke function to all strings from one object

Tags: javascript, string, internationalization

I have a locale object similar to this:

```
L = {
  message: {
    hello: "Hello %s!",
    goodbye: "Farewell %s!"
  }
  error: {
    notfound: {
      title: "Can't find %s!",
      text: "But just where did I put it?"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to add a function that simply return a sprintf'ed version of the string being "invoked" from the object that could be used simply like `return L.message.hello("Ivan")` which would with some magic do the same as `return sprintf(L.message.hello,"Ivan")`.

After some research, I know this far:

- [PHP-i18n](https://github.com/Philipp15b/php-i18n) does so with the help of the magic method `__callStatic` which does not seem to exist in Javascript.
- I could use brute force "deep each" to create methods with the same name as strings, but I don't think it is possible to turn a property into a method and it would be rather ressource intensive.
- `sprintf(L.message.goodbye,"Ivan")` is terrible looking.
- `_(L.error.notfound.title,"the stuff")` actually work! But I find it just one bit not gracious enough.

Is there any way for a gracious and easy implementation to be feasible?

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a setter function for each key of the object if the value is a string. That should help you

For more details

[Refer to Custom setters and getters section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: Sounds like the right path! I think I would probably use the getter function instead than the setter. Can get() take arguments?

Comment: get is to read and set is to write. From the question posted I see that the requirement is to write

Comment: Added more infos. It should actually simply return the sprintf'ed string rather than modify anything from the object.

Answer (score 0):

Even in Ruby on Rails, we used to do the same thing, except which, we have a dedicated function for it. In RoR, we do:

```
_(messages.config.say_hello, current_name)
```

The same way, you can do something like:

```
_ = sprintf;
_(L.message.goodbye,"Ivan");
```

There are 100s of ways you can do I18n. `:)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I do know of _ usage and the npm package i18n-2 makes use of it. I just try to find something a bit more gracious ^^